# Managing libraries dependencies in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

As a beginner with Maven I have a little problem to fully understand and find the best way how to manage all dependencies in my Java Application. In my app there is about 20-30 external libraries. These libraries have own dependency libraries, some of these libraries requires different version of one particular library. How can be this situation solved?

My primary problem is how to find out all dependencies of my librabries and don't forget any of them. When I was searching for a solution I found that http://search.maven.org/ website offers for all libraries own pom.xml file with all dependency libraries that this particular library requires. E.g. this is a pom.xml for [Spring-core 3.2.5](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/springframework/spring-core/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.pom).

What are these files intended for? Can be these files be used in Maven project to specify dependencies? I hope so, because it consists valuable information about one particular library and the structure of this pom.xml file is the same as in the standard Maven pom.xml file.

If can be used directly in Maven, where to place these files? I have studied standard Maven project [directory structure](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) but I have no idea where to place them.

If can't be used, what are these pom.xml files intended for? Is it safe to copy out dependencies and use in my Maven project pom.xml file? This could be a solution how to find out all needed dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all your dependencies in `pom.xml` file(s), yes. That way all required dependencies will automatically be downloaded from Maven repository and packaged into your build artifact. You mostly don't have to worry about anything else than whether you set up the scopes correct. Use dependencyManagement on root project, if you have a multimodule Maven project.

`pom.xml` goes to the root of your project, BTW.

Read more [here](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you have your app's dependencies in the pom.xml file.

The files in repositories carry the information about that particular library dependencies. You don't have to place any additional files besides your application's pom.xml file. Maven will take care of including dependencies of dependencies while packaging your application.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that Maven knows that library A which I am using has as a dependencies B,C,D in some particular version and when I call mvn package command Maven includes all these dependencies? It works as you mentioned even I don't package my app into uber-jar via Maven Shade Plugin? Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Yes, exactly so. All nested dependencies are defined in the `pom.xml` files of your project's dependencies and so on.